# Swift split array to string

Tags: swift

I have an array of location coordinates that are separated by : (-33.1231231:143.12312312) for example.

I am looping over the array to determine how many polygon points I need to create on a Google Map (CLLocationCoordinate2DMake)

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(userCoordinates) {
    println("\(element)")
}
```

I would like to split each element in to 2 parts at the : to create longitude and latitude values and then use these in as the coordinates.

I can't figure out how to split the element in to 2 pieces.

Comment: What is the type of element ? Is it a String ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `element` is a `String` then you can separate do the following :

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(userCoordinates) {

    // If the parenthesis are present you can remove them:
    var stringElmt = element.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

    var elmtArray = split(stringElmt) {$0 == ":"}

    if elmtArray.count == 2 {
        let latitude = elmtArray[0]
        let longitude = elmtArray[1]

        // Do something with latitude and longitude
    }
}
```

The first line separate all the elements in your string with : being the separator and pass the different element in an array that you can then access by subscript.